# Reactor EmitterProcessor that only retains last n elements?

Tags: java, project-reactor, eventemitter

How do I create an `EmitterProcessor` that retains only the *latest* n elements, such that it also works even if there are no subscribers?

At the moment I create a processor like this:

```
EmitterProcessor<Integer> processor = EmitterProcessor.create();
```

And an external system provides temperature updates randomly throughout the day. In the callback from that system I do:

```
void tempConsumer(int temp) {
    processor.onNext(temp);
}
```

However `onNext(...)` blocks once `processor.getBufferSize()` elements have been added.

How can I create a processor that discards the oldest element, in this case, rather than blocking?

This seems to be covered to some degree in [reactor-core #763](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/763). Simon Baslé first discusses a [proposed change](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/763#issuecomment-325953123) to `EmitterProcessor` such that when "sending data while there are NO subscribers [and] the queue contains `bufferSize` elements, the oldest element is dropped and the `onNext` is enqueued." But then in the next comment, he says "we won't go ahead with my suggested change above. We instead advise you to use the `sink()` rather than directly the `onNext`. Namely, to use the `onRequest` callback inside the `sink()` to perform exactly as many `sink.next(...)` as there are requests."

However, if I understand things correctly this only covers the case where you can calculate new elements on demand, e.g. like so:

```
FluxSink<Integer> sink = processor.sink();
Random random = new Random();

sink.onRequest(n -> random.nextInt()); // Generate next n requested elements.
```

But in my situation, I can't *generate* the latest n temperature readings on demand. Of course, I could maintain my own external bounded buffer of the latest readings and then read from that in `onRequest(...)` but I'm assuming Reactor can do this for me?

I presume this question is a dup - but my Google foo has failed me here.

---

Ricard Kollcaku's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54405690/245602) that one should use [`ReplayProcessor`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/ReplayProcessor.html) seems to be the right way to do things. Here is another example that I wrote to get clear in my head how to use it:

```
ReplayProcessor<Integer> flux = ReplayProcessor.create(Queues.SMALL_BUFFER_SIZE);
FluxSink<Integer> sink = flux.sink();

// ReplayProcessor.getBufferSize() returns unbounded,
// while CAPACITY returns the capacity of the underlying buffer.
int capacity = flux.scan(Scannable.Attr.CAPACITY);

// Add twice as many elements as the underlying buffer can take.
int count = capacity * 2;

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    sink.next(i);
}

// If `capacity` is 256, this will print value 256 thru to 511.
flux.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

I also found [this section](https://books.google.ch/books?id=Fv1wDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA74&ots=81bBxFDyS0&dq=reactor%20ReplayProcessor&pg=PA75#v=onepage&q=reactor%20ReplayProcessor&f=false), in [Hands-On Reactive Programming with Reactor](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/hands-reactive-programming-reactor), useful in explaining things.

Comment: You didn't specify the expected behavior for new subscribers. FWIW: `cache()` is the operator equivalent to `ReplayProcessor`.

Comment: `ReplayProcessor` _seems_ to do what I want. New subscribers should receive the last _n_ elements added, before they subscribed, before receiving new elements. The really important thing for me is that the callback that adds new elements to the flux should never block on calling `next` and that the underlying buffer should not grow in an unbounded manner, irrespective of whether there are subscribers or not. It is even acceptable for subscribers to "lose" elements, i.e. miss temperature readings, if they don't consume fast enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use `ReplayProcessor` like this example :

```
 ReplayProcessor<Integer> directProcessor = ReplayProcessor.cacheLast();

    Flux.range(1, 10)
            .map(integer -> {
                directProcessor.onNext(integer);
                return integer;
            }).doOnComplete(() -> {
        directProcessor.subscribe(System.out::println);
        directProcessor.subscribe(System.out::println);
    })
            .subscribe();
```